# Parse arrays of integers and characters in C

Tags: c, arrays, parsing

I've two arrays like these ones:

```
char test_results[] = "20 7 1 12 3"
int  test[]         = {3, 8, 9, 12, 6}
```

I would like to take one by one the numbers of `test_results` and compare it with the numbers of `test` array. If there's any coincidence, print the result.

How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: `strtok`/`strchr`/`strtol` if you don't know the number of numbers in your string, and `sscanf` otherwise?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should be what you need

```
char  text[] = "20 7 1 12 3";
int   test[] = {3, 8, 9, 12, 6};
char *ptr;
int   count;

ptr   = text;
count = sizeof(test) / sizeof(*test);
while (*ptr != '\0')
{
    int value;
    int i;

    value = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);
    for (i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        if (value == test[i])
            printf("there is a coincidence at the %dth number of the array %d\n", i, value);
    }
}
```

it will output

> `there is a coincidence with the 3th number of the array 12`
>   `there is a coincidence with the 0th number of the array 3`

Comment: That works! Thank you. I tried with `sscanf` to pass char to int but `atoi` is better :)